# How to access a component within an item renderer?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a scrollview and a mapped array into a render item, the render item has a text component and a button component, how would I pass a reference to the text component when the button is pressed?

I am listing the scrollivew and render item as abstract for simplicity:

```
<ScrollView>
{this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
                      return (
                        <RenderItem
                          item={item}
                        />
                      );
                    }
</ScrollView>
```

The render item:

```
class RenderItem extends React.PureComponent {

render() {
    const {item} = this.props;

    return (
     <View>
        {/* I NEED TO PASS THIS TEXT COMPONENT */}
        <Text >{item.txt}</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => {                
          this.props.onPressPlay(item, textRef ?);
          }}>                
        </Button>
     </View>
);
}
```

So, the `textRef` should be a reference to the `<Text>` component at the same item renderer.

Any idea?

Comment: As i know you can't create a reference ```on-the-fly```. But you can create an Array of references and pass proper one as prop to child. (Ref forwarding : https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)